# Screen flickering when there is much on the screen

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, screen, amd-graphics, amd-processor

***System:***

- Memory: **6.8GiB**
- Processor: **AMD Ryzen 5 2500u with radeon vega mobile gfx x 8**
- Graphics: **AMD Raven**
- GNOME: **3.34.2**
- OS type: **64-bit**
- Ubuntu Version: **19.10**

***Problem:***

Since a while now, whenever there is more going on on the screens (i use two monitors, one vertical), the image flickers, meaning I can't see the content of the screen but only see a kind of noise. Moving the page a bit removes it for a while, until it happens again. Typical reasons for this are, watching a video and browsing the web at the same time. When i was first using Ubuntu it didn't happen, but one day it appeared and I can't figure out how to solve this and it's really getting on my nerves.
I'm pretty new to Linux and all that stuff, so if you need extra information, just let me know.

Comment: Does this happen on both monitors? And by the way... You are using a laptop, right?

Comment: Have you been upgrading your system, kernel? Have you tried to run video and web browsing on different LiveCDs? You could try it and answer your question if the situation reproduces for some kernels and does not reproduces on others.

Comment: @Smooth Researcher: Yes I am using a Huawei Laptop and the problem happens on both screen, not always at the same time, but it happened.

Comment: @Gryu: I am currently using Kernel: Linux 5.3.0-29-generic. I have updated it an nothing changed, so i assume it's the latest version